# Switching from JSON to YAML

Tags: jss

The basic-sample-react-native project comes with the data routes setup in a JSON file. Can you tell me what the steps are for using a YAML file instead?

I swapped out the JSON file for a valid YAML file and changed the routeData path within dataService.disconnected.js. There must be another configuration step somewhere though, as that did not work for me.

Comment: Because of the experimental nature of react-native in JSS, the react-native sample is not up-to-date with the same patterns/practices as the other framework samples (React, Angular, Vue). I'll make note to look into updating the react-native sample as much as is realistic. Many of the disconnected mode  features of the other samples are not possible for react-native.

Answer (score 4):

As YAML is a superset of JSON, any valid JSON is also valid YAML.

However, if you're looking for idiomatic YAML just run the JSON through a converter like https://www.json2yaml.com/

Comment: I think I'm trying to go the opposite direction of what you mentioned. I have JSON already, but I'd like to use YAML. Since YAML is not valid JSON, I don't think I can just swap out.

Based on Adam's comment above, it sounds like the react-native sample just can't do YAML at the moment. Is that correct?